# match_phrase_prefix doesnt return result obtained by match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch

The match phrase query

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "approved_labelled_products.companies": "SOMETHING INC"
    }
  }
```

returns a particular result but
the match_phrase_prefix query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "approved_labelled_products.companies": "SOME.*"
    }
  }
}
```

return an empty result set

```
"hits": 
{
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
 }
```

The match_phrase_prefix must atleast return the data that has been obtained by the match_phrase query but it doesnt.

the mapping for the data is as follows

```
    "approved_labelled_products": {
            "properties": {
              "companies": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "null_value": "NULL",
                "ignore_above": 9500
              }
             }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`match_phrase`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) and [`match_phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) queries are full-text search queries and require the data field to be of [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/text.html) type. It is very much different from the [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/keyword.html) type you are using, now let me explain what you can do now and what is the difference.

### Can I make `match_phrase_prefix` work?

Yes, you can use [`match_phrase_prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) if you change the type of the field to `text`.

### How can I search for a prefix using `keyword` field?

`keyword` is stored and queried as-is, without any [analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis.html). Think about it as a single string; to find all documents that have such field with given prefix it is enough to use a [`prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query.

Let's define our mapping and insert a couple of documents:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "approved_labelled_products": {
          "properties": {
            "companies": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "null_value": "NULL",
              "ignore_above": 9500
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST myindex/_doc
{
  "approved_labelled_products": {
    "companies": "SOMETHING INC"
  }
}
```

Now we can issue a query like this:

```
POST myindex/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "approved_labelled_products.companies": "SOME"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that, since there is literally no analysis performed, the request is case-sensitive, and querying by string `"some"` will not return results.

### How is `text` field different?

[`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/text.html) field is [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis.html) during indexing time, which means the input string is split into tokens, lowercased, some meta-information is saved and an [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) is constructed.

This allows to fetch documents containing certain token or combination of tokens efficiently.

To illustrate this we can use [_analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-analyze.html). Let's try to see how Elasticsearch would analyze the data for `keyword` field first:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "keyword",
  "text": "SOMETHING INC"
}
```

This will return:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "SOMETHING INC",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it is a single token with all capital letters.

Now let's see what `standard` analyzer does (the one that `text` field uses by default):

```
POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text": "SOMETHING INC"
}
```

It will return:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "something",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "inc",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, it has produced two tokens, both lowercased.

---

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use wildcard expression in `match_phrase_prefix` query.

Use this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "approved_labelled_products.companies": "SOME"
    }
  }
}
```